# Second Language for Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, programming-languages

I want to pursue Machine Learning and Data Science as a future career and wanted to get your advice on a good second language that will be useful in the ML field. Currently, I am learning Python and using libraries such as Pandas and Tensorflow to create some practical projects. However, for a job, I feel like I would need a second language to supplement Python. What recommendation do you guys have for a second language? Additionally, if you know of any resources or materials that could help me accelerate my learning in this area, I would appreciate any recommendations you may have.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sorry about the general question. I just wanted to know if there is a second language other than Python that is highly used in the Machine Learning/ Data Science industry to build Machine Learning models.

Comment: Python has been quite important, I personally use it for my job, mostly to write APIs and custom actions/classifiers, otherwise, probably you can learn R and SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you learn SQL as your second language. Most data scientists need to pull data from SQL databases. That doesn't mean you won't have to deal with NoSQL databases, but SQL is more common. If you don't know SQL, you will always need to ask someone who knows it and will be at their mercy to give you what you want. A data scientist should understand their data's provenance and pedigree, the data model, schema, data dictionaries, and how to query the database.

Here is a course by Coursera for furthering your career: [Databases and SQL for Data Science with Python](https://www.coursera.org/learn/sql-data-science?specialization=ibm-data-science&utm_source=gg&utm_medium=sem&campaignid=1876641588&utm_campaign=10-IBM-Data-Science-US&utm_content=B2C&adgroupid=117357906417&device=c&keyword=&matchtype=&network=g&devicemodel=&adpostion=&creativeid=507196710149&hide_mobile_promo&gclid=Cj0KCQiA9YugBhCZARIsAACXxeIWH5wr5pNU4RmWxUFwN037Kl68yN5sEezDAkoQFSu0U9TlDJfv3b8aAs_4EALw_wcB)

Comment: Would you recommend learning a second language to perform Machine Learning, or is knowing Python enough to build the machine learning models? I've read articles talking about how companies use Python to build the model but use faster languages such as C++ to deploy the model, and I don't know if I have to know C++ as well to get hired as a Machine Learning Engineer.

Comment: Python is enough for most jobs. C++ is a great language to know, but most ML people don't know it and don't need it.